# How to find an element, which is on the other page at all, with React Testing Library?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to find the element, which doesn't currently exist but is presented on the other page of the app URL:(http://localhost:3000/step2), because there is a need to test that element. So, I did kind of a multi-step form, but those steps were implemented with React Router.

I know when some element is not currently presented, in this case, we should use **findBy...**,
which will return a promise with the founded element ...

I wrote a code according to documentation:

```
 const email = await screen.findByRole('textbox', {
            name: /email/i,
        })
        console.log(email)
```

but my terminal displays me this message error:

```
Unable to find role="textbox"
```

Bare HTML looks like this:

```
<div
  class="MuiFormControl-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth MuiTextField-root css-wb57ya-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root"
><label
    class="MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-root MuiFormLabel-colorPrimary MuiFormLabel-filled css-1kty9di-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root"
    data-shrink="true"
    for="mui-3"
    id="mui-3-label"
  >Email</label>
  <div
    class="MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl css-md26zr-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root"
  ><input
      aria-invalid="false"
      name="email"
      type="text"
      class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input css-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input"
      value="218855@ukr.net"
      id="mui-3"
    >
    <fieldset
      aria-hidden="true"
      class="MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline"
    >
      <legend class="css-1z7n62"><span>Email</span></legend>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can copy my snippet of HTML code and paste it into this resource: https://testing-playground.com/  to make sure that the role is right.

What do I do wrong?
How to find that needed element?

Answer (score 1):

You can render a component with router, especially [MemoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/memory-router), which is there for test purpose.

I would suggest give the initialEntry as step1, simulate the code that redirects to step2 and wait for email textbox to be seen.

Example

```
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

test('TEST_NAME',(fieldName: string) => {
      render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/step1']}>
          <YOUR_COMPONENT/>
        </MemoryRouter>,
      );
      // write test logic 

      // assert email is in the document.
      expect(await screen.findByRole('textbox', {
            name: /email/i,
      })).toBeInTheDocument();
    },
  );
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate it in a very simple way?

Comment: I need some visual example.

Comment: @AlexKor attached simple example

Comment: Judging by your example. I need to indicate ""initialEntries** with the URL where my needed element is. Am I right?

Comment: You also said, "simulate the code that redirects to step2". How to do that?

Comment: Say that your page, step1 renders a form and if you submit that, page will go to step2. If that's the real use-case, what you need to do is submitting a form inside 'simulate the logic' block. And you should start with step1 as initialEntries.